# How to number enumerate as 1.01, 1.02.. 1.10

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

Is there a way I can change enumerate to create a list as follows?

```
1.01
1.02
1.03
1.04
1.05
1.06
1.07
1.08
1.09
1.10
1.11
...
```

I've been using enumitem as follows, but it's not the right approach:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

    \begin{enumerate}[label=1.0\arabic*, nosep]
    \item a
    \item b
    \item c
    \item d
    \item e
    \item f
    \item g
    \item h
    \item i
    \item j
    \item k
    \end{enumerate}
    
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use package `padcount`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{padcount}
\setpadnum{2}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
  \begin{enumerate}[label=1.\protect\padnum{\arabic*}, nosep]
    \item a
    \item b
    \item c
    \item d
    \item e
    \item f
    \item g
    \item h
    \item i
    \item j
    \item k
  \end{enumerate}  
\end{document}
```